# How can I debug multiple instances of an Asp.Net app in a container?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm developing a stateless Asp.Net app that runs in Kubernetes, so there's many instances of it running at once.

I want to debug it this way as well, so that I can spot bugs that might not happen if you debug on just a single instance. Think of authentication cookies not working correctly for example: works great on one instance, not at all if you don't set up data protection correctly.

Is there a way to run and debug multiple instances of the same Asp.Net project in Visual Studio 2019?